# Add custom gesture to flutter slidable

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm trying to build a list that when the user swipes the list item from left to right a slidable pan shows up and when the user swipes from right to left, the list item text style changes (adding an underline and changing color).
I can't combine these two functionalities.

[image]

[image]

I've tried to combine dissmisable with slidable but somhow dissmisable overrides slidable.

---

Just Slidable code (works good):

```
ListView(
      children: [
        Slidable(
          key: const ValueKey(0),
          endActionPane: ActionPane(
            extentRatio: 0.25,
            motion: const StretchMotion(),
            children: [
              SlidableAction(
                onPressed: (context) {},
                foregroundColor: Colors.black,
                icon: Icons.edit,
              ),
              SlidableAction(
                onPressed: (context) {},
                foregroundColor: Colors.red,
                icon: Icons.delete,
              ),
            ],
          ),
          child: const ListTile(
            title: Text('Sample Task'),
          ),
        ),
      ],
    ),
```

---

Slidable + Dismissable (doesn't behave ok):

```
ListView(
      children: [
        Slidable(
          key: const ValueKey(0),
          endActionPane: ActionPane(
            extentRatio: 0.25,
            motion: const StretchMotion(),
            children: [
              SlidableAction(
                onPressed: (context) {},
                foregroundColor: Colors.black,
                icon: Icons.edit,
              ),
              SlidableAction(
                onPressed: (context) {},
                foregroundColor: Colors.red,
                icon: Icons.delete,
              ),
            ],
          ),
          child: Dismissible(
            key: const ValueKey(0),
            child: const ListTile(
              title: Text('Sample Task'),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ],
    ),
```

Comment: can you attach the code you have tried?

Comment: @MunsifAli I've added the code to the question body

Comment: what's error are you getting?

Comment: When I add dismissable to the code (second code) and swipe rtl the slidable doesn't show up and the list item disappears. I'm looking for a way to keep slidable for rtl swipe and add another gesture for ltr gesture. @MunsifAli

Comment: do you tried to used listview.builder?

Answer (score -1):

```
GestureDetector(
          onHorizontalDragUpdate: (details) {
            int sensitivity = 10;
            if (details.delta.dx > sensitivity) {
              setState(() {
                result = "swiped right direction";
              });
            } else if (details.delta.dx < -sensitivity) {
              setState(() {
                result = "swiped left direction";
              });
            }
          },
          child: const ListTile(
            title: Text('Sample Task'),
          ),
        ),
```

you can write these codes.

Comment: I'm actually looking for a way to keep slidable for rtl swipe and add another gesture for ltr gesture.